# Stored procedure return error -2147217913 after execute command.adodb with parameters

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql

This is correct but return error code converting data type

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[USp_TB_INFO_Insert] 
    (@idinfo INT OUTPUT,
     @infotext VARCHAR(200) = NULL,
     @lpriority INT = NULL,
     @sdate_ini CHAR(20) = NULL,
     @sdate_end CHAR(20) = NULL,
     @active BIT = NULL,
     @namefile VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @fkgroup INT = NULL,
     @username VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @user VARCHAR(200) = NULL,
     @log BIT = 1)
AS
   BEGIN TRAN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @deleted BIT
   DECLARE @date_ini DATETIME
   DECLARE @date_end DATETIME

   SET @deleted = 0

   IF @sdate_ini IS NULL
   BEGIN
       SET @date_ini = getdate()
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       SET @date_ini = CAST(@sdate_ini AS DATETIME)
   END

   IF @sdate_end IS NULL
   BEGIN
       SET @date_end = NULL
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       SET @date_end = CAST(@sdate_end AS DATETIME)
   END

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[TB_INFO] ([infotext], [lpriority], [date_ini], [date_end], 
                                [active], [namefile], [fkgroup], [deleted], [username])
   VALUES (@infotext, @lpriority, @date_ini, @date_end,
           @active, @namefile, @fkgroup, @deleted, @username);

   COMMIT TRAN 

   SET @idinfo = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
   SET NOCOUNT OFF;

   IF @log = 1
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @RC INT
       DECLARE @idlog INT

       EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[USp_TB_LOG_Insert] 
             @idlog OUTPUT, 'INSERT', @user, 'TB_INFO', @idinfo
   END
```

una command.adodb with parameters returns error:

> Error converting data type varchar to int
>   number:-2147217913

and my sub routine (new):

```
 Public Sub SaveInfoOPE()

   Dim cmInsertInfo As ADODB.Command
   Dim iReturnValue As Integer
   ' create a ADO command for StoredProcedure [dbo].[USp_TB_INFO_Insert]
   If ValidateDataOpe() Then
      On Error GoTo errcommand
      Set cmInsertInfo = New ADODB.Command
      Set cmInsertInfo.ActiveConnection = mcn ' is = "DSN=INFOPOINT"
      With cmInsertInfo
          .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
          .CommandText = "dbo.USp_TB_INFO_Insert"


         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@infotext", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(infotext))
         .Parameters("@infotext").Value = infotext   'present value='Printer out'
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@lpriority", adInteger, adParamInput)
         .Parameters("@lpriority").Value = Priority  'present value='1'
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@sDate_ini", adChar, adParamInput, 20)
         .Parameters("@sDate_ini").Value = Date_Ini   'present value='08/03/2019 13:40:07'

         '******** not for OPE *****
         'If Not Date_End = "" Then
          ' .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@sDate_end", adChar, adParamInput, 20)
          ' .Parameters("@sDate_end").Value = Date_End
         'End If
         '*************************************

         If Not Len(namefile & "") = 0 Then
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@namefile", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(namefile))
           .Parameters("@namefile").Value = namefile  'present value=""
         End If

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@username", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(UserName))
        .Parameters("@username").Value = UserName 'present value='alip'
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@user", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(User))
        .Parameters("@user").Value = User 'present value='AL'

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@fkgroup", adInteger, adParamInput)
        .Parameters("@fkgroup").Value = FkGroup  'present value='1'
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@active", adInteger, adParamInput)
        .Parameters("@active").Value = IIf(Active, 1, 0)  'present active value='True'
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@log", adInteger, adParamInput)
        .Parameters("@log").Value = IIf(Log, 1, 0) 'present log value='true'
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamReturnValue, , Null)

        On Error GoTo errcmexecute
       .Execute
       iReturnValue = .Parameters(0)
     End With
     RaiseEvent DatInsert(True, "")
   End If


   '************ close command
   exitcommand:
   Set cmInsertInfo = Nothing
 Exit Sub

 errcommand:
     MsgBox "error: " & err.Description & vbCrLf _
     & "number: " & err.Number, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Procedure Command Save"
     RaiseEvent DatInsert(False, "")
     GoTo exitcommand
 errcmexecute:
     MsgBox "error: " & err.Description & vbCrLf _
     & "number: " & err.Number, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Procedure Command Save"
     RaiseEvent DatInsert(False, "")
     GoTo exitcommand
End Sub
```

`command.adodb.execute` returns error:

> Error converting data type varchar to int.
>   number:-2147217913

Please help me

Thanks for all

Comment: In SQL you have `USp_TB_INFO_Update`. From VB you call `USp_TB_INFO_Insert`.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you declaring your parameters in SQL as an `nvarchar`, but in your vba declaring it as a `adVarChar` and not a `adVarWChar`? If you do have any non-ANSI characters, they would be lost in the application.

Comment: And why do you declare your date parameters as char(25)? It seems you may need to work on your schema and your stored procedure code first to use proper datatypes. Otherwise, this path will lead to many, many issues in the future.

Comment: excuse me, I copied the storeprocedureUpdate instead of insert more or less equal

Comment: The change from advarchar to advarwchar not resolve

Comment: into storeprocedure i cast: SET @date_ini = cast(@sdate_ini as datetime)

Comment: You can check a `CAST`for success with`TRY_CAST` . If CAST failed Null is returned, what you can check: `CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(@sdate_ini as datetime) IS NULL`

Comment: You missed to turn on the  Command.NamedParameters Property. That causes the  Parameters to be passed by append order. [Error converting data type varchar to int](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/127342.aspx).